# batch updating of Database Table data in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

HiI have two tables.

**tbl1**

```
id             int(11)      NOT NULL

positionName   varchar(20)  NULL

positionId     int(11)      NULL
```

**tbl2**

```
positionId         int(11)      NOT NULL

positionName       varchar(20)  NULL
```

Originally, there is no column `positionId` in `tbl1`. Now will use `positionId` instead of `positionName` for `tbl1`.

The problem is there are over thousands of data already stored in both tables.

So, How can I successfully and quickly link to the correct `positionId` for the each data of `tbl1` , in which `positionName` was previously used?

Is batch updating is a way?

Is there anyway that I can perform all things with SQL browser? If possible, I don't want to use coding.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a multiple-table [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), like this?

```
UPDATE tbl1
JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.positionName = tbl2.positionName
SET tbl1.positionId = tbl2.positionId
WHERE tbl1.positionId IS NULL
```

I'm assuming that `positionName` is unique in `tbl2`, but if it isn't, you'll need to consider how you wish to handle that.

Comment: NICE solution. Thanks you so much. works very well. Yes `positionName` is unique in `tbl2`